# How to interpret の here?

Tags: grammar, manga

For context, a speaker got her friend to help her to carry her belongings to a storage room and her friend collapsed. The below panel shows the speaker explaining her situation to somebody.

[image]

I have trouble deciding whether the の here is a nominalizer or a sentence-ending particle. If it is the latter, then how 運んでもらうの is understood? I'd be fine with 運ぶの. もらう is redundant to me in this case.

Maybe I should add that the speaker recently moved to a new place and all her stuff is stored in a moving truck. Maybe the moving company is responsible for 運ぶ?

Answer (score 1):

This の is a nominalizer, and を has been omitted after it. The action of 荷物(を)運んでもらう is working as the subject of 手伝う.

> 物置に荷物(を)運んでもらうの(を)手伝ってもらってて、…
> I was having her help me move my stuff into the storage, and ...

The two もらう *do* look a little redundant to me. An improved version of this sentence is 物置に荷物(を)運ぶの(を)手伝ってもらってて. Still, having two もらう does not make this sentence incorrect (and の as a sentence-ending particle does not make sense to me in this context).